# How to "Delete rows ignoring errors" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I need to remove some rows in my DB (MySQL) and don't matter for me if this row doesn't exist in the database. In other words, I need delete rows ignoring the errors.

**I know the following command:**

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO MyTable (field1, field2) values (value1, value2);
```

That insert in my database the values, regardless if it already exist or not. I already go to [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) but I didn't find a good answer to this question. Also, I see some questions in StackOverflow, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303159/how-do-i-ignore-errors-when-deleting-records), that don't helped me.

---

**So, exist in MySQL a command like below?**

```
DELETE IGNORE from MyTable where myField = myValue;
```

Comment: Just run the delete query,if there are values there they will be deleted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Regular delete:

```
DELETE  from MyTable where myField = myValue;
```

will delete all rows matching condition `myField = myValue`. Situation when there are no such rows is not an error and simply nothing will be deleted.

Comment: Oh, thanks @Secator. Just a newbie question, sorry :/